# How to view Parent of branch git

Tags: git

I created a branch from an already existing branch, Now in my wisdom i cannot remember what that branch name was. Does anyone know to find out the name of the branch your branch was created from?

Comment: How about looking at it in gitk?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Looking at the [git docs](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History) would have given you your answer quicker than Stack Overflow, but while you're here, try this:

```
git log --graph --decorate
```

It will print your commit history while showing you the branch topology that got you where you are. If you want to see the history with all the branches you can add the `--all` flag as well.

Comment: It's not true that command gives you a branch topology such that you can know the parent of branch. Try for example a branch created from a branch that is a branch of master. After some commits you that command gives you no clue.

Comment: How could I fetch only name of the parent branch?

Answer (score 2):

This will show you only the commits that are unique to you branch plus any commits that you branched off of or merge into your current branch. The commit(s) that the current branch are branched from will be listed with a leading `o` instead of a `*`.

```
git log --decorate --oneline --graph --boundary HEAD \
   --not --exclude=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD) --glob=refs/*
```

Sample Output:

```
* 493aaed (HEAD, my-branch) Fixed Typo
o 012788f (master) Merged in release/1.1.1
```

Please be aware that the base commit may not be associated with a branch anymore if the original branch also progressed. In that case you will then need to execute the following command to determine which branches diverge from that commit.

```
git branch -a --contains <boundary-commit>
```

In the case above, the boundary commit is 012788f.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! if anyone wants just the branch name you can do this: `git log --decorate --oneline --graph --boundary HEAD --not --exclude=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD) --glob=refs/* | grep -e '^o' | sed 's/^.* (\(.*\)).*/\
1/'`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore... I get no output... at least in a MINGW64 shell on Windows that I'm trying it out in...

Answer (score 2):

I think the right answer to this question should be:

```
git show-branch --list
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is actually not an answer to the question, because the question is about figuring something out about the history of the branch, where it was created from in the first place, whereas your command only show current information about the branch.

Answer (score 1):

This command displays the history of commits and indicates the parent branch.

```
 git show-branch --current
```